# Cached crystal reports controls on Toolbox in VS 2005 and VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I have a couple duplicate custom crystal reports controls in my Toolbox in VS2005 and VS2008. One of each of the duplicates is preceded with the word Cached. These controls are all part of other projects in the same solution. I have removed some of the main controls that I don't want on the Toolbox by adding the [ToolboxItem(false)] attribute on the control, but the cached one remains. How do I remove these cached controls from the Toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you add a Crystal Report to your project it creates two classes in the .cs file. The second class has the same name as the first named class except that the word Cached is added to it. Just added [ToolboxItem(false)] to the second class as well.